# Django Datetime formate DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: django, datetime

I want to set the date format  DD-MM-YYYY
but Error django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“23.07.2023 21:00:11” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']

Help Me

````
create_date = models.DateField(blank=False, default=datetime.now().strftime(("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")))```


I want to set the date format  DD-MM-YYYY 
but Error django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“23.07.2023 21:00:11” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
````

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your model form**

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'create_date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'input_format': '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'}),
        }
```

Comment: model is error 
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'

Comment: Try above modelform if  you are using via modelform.Send me your code if it does not work via github link and I will make it work .I will run and check it.

Comment: If I can't use form.py? 

def changstatus(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_id = taskjob.objects.get(id=id)
        if task_id.status == False:
            task_id.status = True
        else:
            task_id.status = False
        dt = datetime.now()
        formatted_dt = dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
        task_id.compalte_date = formatted_dt
        task_id.save()
        return redirect('/')
    return redirect('/')